# need help in Gammu smsd file configuration

Tags: sms-gateway, gammu

What i have edited in the smsdrc file:

```
[smsd]
# SMSD service to use, one of FILES, MYSQL, PGSQL, DBI
service = MYSQL
user = root
password = 
pc = localhost
driver = native_mysql
```

but nothing happen to save into the MySQL database,
I am using Windows 7 with Wamp Server.

Which part of this configuration is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my config file and it works:

```
4 [gammu]
5 # Please configure this!
6 port = /dev/ttyUSB1
7 connection = AT
8 # Debugging
9 #logformat = textall
10
11 # SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
12 [smsd]
13 service = sql
14 driver = native_mysql
15 logfile = 
16 pin = 1111
17 User = root
18 Password = password
19 PC = localhost
20 Database = smsd
21 InboxFormat = standard
```

The AT connection is used if you don't have nokia-phone.